# Who pays when using BigQuery Storage Read API across projects?

Tags: google-bigquery

Say that I have two projects in GCP, Projects A and B. Project A has a BigQuery table, and project B needs to read that data using the BigQuery Storage Read API.

If I create a service account in project B, then go to project A and assign this user the role `BigQuery Read Session User` as well as add them to the dataset ACL, they will be able to stream the table content. Which project will receive the bill for the data extracted? Project A where the read session is created, or Project B which is the home of the acting service account?

To be clear, I would like for Project B to pay for the load they generate.

I have tried to find a way to be explicit about this, but as far as I can tell there is no way to specify billing project when creating a read session. I have also checked what happens when I try to create a read session with the "parent project" set to Project B while the table location says Project A, and this just leads to the table not being found at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Storage Read API pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#overview_of_pricing), BigQuery charges for the number of bytes processed (also referred to as bytes read). In your scenario, Project A has the Bigquery table and where the Read Session happens and you just attached Project B's service account as `BigQuery Read Session User` in Project A, hence the billed amount will go to Project A.

As an alternative, you can check using [Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#filtering_and_grouping) the cost trends for Bigquery Storage API with the following filters:

[image]
[image]